# NullPointerException at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source) no Java com Lucene

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro no meu código em Java

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Indexador.indexaArquivosDoDiretorio(Indexador.java:42)
    at Princ$1$1.run(Princ.java:235)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Não sei por que começou a dar esse erro, acredito que seja algo relacionado aos objetos do tipo File não aceitarem String. Segue o código:

```
public void indexaArquivosDoDiretorio() {
    try {
        Properties prop = getProp();
        // Diretório que irá guardar o índice;
        String diretorioDosIndices = prop.getProperty("diretorio.indice");
        // Diretório que contém os documentos que serão indexados;
        String diretorioParaIndexar = prop.getProperty("diretorio.fonte");
        File diretorio = new File(diretorioDosIndices);
        apagaIndices(diretorio);
        // Directory: representa o diretório do índice;
        Directory d = new SimpleFSDirectory(diretorio);
        // Analyser/StandardAnalyser: fazem o pré-processamento do texto.
        // Existem analisadores inclusive em português;
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_47);
        // IndexWriterConfig: configurações para criação do índice. No
        // projeto serão utilizados os valores padrão;
        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_47,
                analyzer);
        // Inicializa o IndexWriter para gravação;
        writer = new IndexWriter(d, config);
        long inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
        indexaArquivosDoDiretorio(new File(diretorioParaIndexar));
        // Fecha o IndexWriter e comita as mudanças
        writer.commit();
        writer.close();
        long fim = System.currentTimeMillis();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null,
                "Quantidade de arquivos indexados: " + i + "\n"
                        + "Tempo para indexar: "
                        + String.valueOf((fim - inicio) / 1000) + "s");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }
}
```

Linha 42:

```
File diretorio = new File(diretorioDosIndices);
```

Comment: Você chegou a debugar e ver qual o conteúdo da variável `diretorioDosIndices`?

Comment: Tentei, mas o Eclipse não para nos breaks ou não chega neles.

Comment: Tentou fazer um `sysout` para ver o conteúdo da variável `diretorioDosIndices`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File` possui construtor que recebe como argumento uma instância de `String`, veja o javadoc do construtor.

> File(String pathname)
>   Creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname string into an abstract pathname.

Essa exceção ocorre por conta do argumento passado no construtor ser `null`, nesse caso a variável `diretorioDosIndices` está nula.

No construtor de `File` que recebe `String` como argumento existe a seguinte documentação para exceções lançadas:

> Throws:
>   NullPointerException - If the pathname argument is null

Java doc retirado desse [endereço](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html).

Por fim, verifique a obtenção do valor da variável `diretorioDosIndices`, pois não há dúvidas que a chamada `prop.getProperty("diretorio.indice")` não encontra a propriedade e por essa razão retorna `null`.

Comment: Realmente, o valor estava null. Mas o motivo está muito estranho, pois eu tive que alterar o nome do prop por que estava dando conflito com outro que eu uso na mesma classe.